# How to setup a detached task that throws an error

Tags: swift, task

I'm trying to create a detached task that can throw an error. Here's a synthesized example of what I have.

```
 @MainActor
  var eventHandlerTask: Task<(), Never>? = nil

  func eventsHandler(events: [BEIEvent]) async throws {
    eventHandlerTask = Task.detached { [weak self] in
       throw NSError()
    }
  }
```

Xcode complains with: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '@Sendable () throws -> Bool' to non-throwing function type '@Sendable () async -> Bool'

[image]

How can I setup a detached task that throws?

Comment: call `eventsHandler` inside your `Task.detatched`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `eventHandlerTask` to have a `Failure` type of `Never`. So it cannot throw an error.

However, if you change `Never` to `Error`, then it can take a closure that throws errors:

```swift
var eventHandlerTask: Task<(), Error>?
```